# Apache2 - multiple sites, easiest setup

Tags: apache, multiple-sites

I'd like to use mod_vhost_alias for ease of site setup in Apache2.2. So I'd have my virtual host setup something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/%0"
</VirtualHost>
```

What I'd also like to do on a per site basis, is to include an extra config file - something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/%0"
    Include "/var/www/%0/http.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

But Apache doesn't seem to like this. Is there any other way of achieving this?

Thanks,

James.

Comment: This might be a question that fits better at http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the other way around: include a directory in your main configuration file, and have one configuration file for each site in there. E.g.

*http.conf*

```
Include /apache/sites/
```

*/apache/sites/site1.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *>
  host specific configuration here..
</VirtualHost *>
```